# Remove some duplicated columns & rename others based on conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a dataframe that looks like this:

```
     Sample_1  Sample_2  Sample_1 Sample_2
1979 0.22      0.50      0.22     0.67
1980 0.15      0.30      0.15     0.77
```

I want to remove duplicated `Sample_1`, because they are identical (they have the same values for the same years). However, I want to keep `Sample_2` because even though the name is duplicated, the values aren't - so I want to rename these types of duplicated columns something else in order to keep them (for example `Sample_2_edit` or `Sample_2_`).

How can I do this?

Comment: Is it a matrix or data.frame?  `data.frame` wouldn't allow duplicate names

Comment: Hi akrun! It's a data.table

Comment: Can you show the dput as it won't allow the row names as well

Comment: If it is a matrix, it makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data is a `matrix` as `data.frame` or `data.table` wouldn't allow duplicate column names and `data.table` doesn't even allow row names.  We can apply `duplicated` on the column names and the values i.e. columns of the data split into a `list` (`asplit`).  Drop those columns that are duplicate for both cases and then rename the duplicate columns by making it unique with `make.unique`

```
m2 <-  m1[, !(duplicated(asplit(m1, 2)) & duplicated(colnames(m1))), drop = FALSE]
colnames(m2) <- make.unique(colnames(m2))
```

-output

```
m2
#     Sample_1 Sample_2 Sample_2.1
#1979     0.22      0.5       0.67
#1980     0.15      0.3       0.77
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(0.22, 0.15, 0.5, 0.3, 0.22, 0.15, 0.67, 0.77), .Dim = c(2L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(c("1979", "1980"), c("Sample_1", "Sample_2", 
"Sample_1", "Sample_2")))
```

Comment: Sorry akrun - it was a matrix, I got confused. Thank you so much for your help :)